# Adjusting weight updates in a generative model

Tags: generative-model

Suppose I am training a generative model *G* to produce vectors *z* in *R^d*, where *d* is fixed. The objective of *G* is to produce realistic vectors, which I am calling the *"reality objective"*. Further suppose that *G* produces *"plausible*" and *"implausible"* vectors during training and I have a second model *E*, which can tell whether the vector is plausible or not. *E* is trained separately under what I call the *"plausibility obective"*. In this context, plausibility is a weaker constraint than being realistic, i.e. everything that is realistic is plausible, but not everything that is plausible is realistic. Moreover, training *E* is far easier than training *G*.

How do I best combine *G* and *E* ? Can I let *E* output a score *r* which I then use to reweight the weight update for *G* toward more plausible outputs? The issue is that, sometimes, weight updates through backprop will lead *G* into regions of the space *R^d* which are implausible. This is easier to tell for *E* than for *G*.

I would like to prevent *G* from venturing into implausible space through the involvement of *E*. Is there a name to what I am trying to do and do you know of a feasible method?

Comment: How do you train G to produce realistic vectors? And then what is the difference between plausible and realistic? Do you have a mathematical definition for that? And Im sure you heard of GANs which combine a generator and discriminator module?

Comment: G is a GAN in my case and it is learning in a latent space z provided by a variational autoencoder (VAE). VAEs are known to suffer from the prior hole problem (some latent vectors are not reconstructed to valid outputs). I want to guide the GAN's optimisation s.t. it only considers latent vectors z which are valid. In other words, all my data are transformed into latent space, and learning as well as backprop for the GAN also occurs in latent space. I want to prevent gradient updates from venturing into regions of "implausible" vectors z of the VAE.

Comment: To answer your other question, realistic means the discriminator assigns the vectors a high score. Plausible means that any vector generated by G can be reconstructed from the latent space z to a valid output. Unfortunately, I do not have a mathematical definition for plausiblility. In this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.00321), they are tryingt to gauge the prior hole problem by counting the consistent units in the bottleneck of the VAE. However, they do not provide an explanation for this.

Comment: Let me know if I can improve my question or whether I should ask it differently.